# React Native - Reveal modal with option to show more upon tapping it

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a form that once completed, a Result component will slide up on the screen showing a score. There will be a TouchableHighlight on this component so that once pressed, the Result component will slide up more to reveal more details about the result. So something like below where completing the form will make my Result component appear with a button to reveal more information.

```
Show result
|--------------------------|
|   Result Score: 100   ^  |
|                          |
|--------------------------|
______________________________
Click on arrow to reveal more information
|--------------------------|
|   Result Score: 100      |
|                          |
|   Some more info         |
|--------------------------|
```

At the moment, my result component appears by manipulating styles and changing the flex value, but this results in shrinking my form to fit the results. I was thinking if a better solution was to render a modal as it doesn't matter if form is covered by the results. I'm looking for recommendations to implement this.

Comment: While I can't directly answer it, here's an example I chopped up for you real quickly: [View example here](https://jsfiddle.net/no52uamL/)

Answer (score 0):

You should understand how `flex` works. Think of it as dividing a whole into portions. When adding content you will need to increase the vertical height of the container.

The simplest way to handle dynamically generated and variable height content is to put the content in a `scrollview`. You can set `contentContainerStyle` to something like `{ alignItems: 'stretch', alignSelf: 'stretch' }` and avoid defining `flex` on the children of scrollview so they take up only as much space as needed and grow as needed.

This may not work well with all use cases though. Sometimes you really don't want a `scrollview`. I just suggest this method as one of the simplest.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved similar things with this layout

```
render {
  return (
    <View>
      <ScrollView/>
      <FooterComponent/>
    </View>
  )
}
```

The footer component will receive an absolute position on the bottom of the `View` and the `ScrollView` will display the regular content.
When required, I can show the `FooterComponent` or even use the Animation API to slide it in.
Then you can either render a Modal to "show more" or increase the size of the `FooterComponent` to span the entire height.